# How many exotic items can I use at once?

Tags: destiny

I read in some forum that players can only equip one exotic item at a time. Is this true? And what happens if you try to equip two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can equip two exotic items: one weapon and one armor.

Different sources: [1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70108674),[2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70063830),[3](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2945l2/legendaryexotic_armor_perks/cihouzv)

Whenever you have an exotic weapon equipped, other exotic weapons in your inventory will appear disabled (dark yellow) and you're unable to equip them until you unequip the one you have equipped.

The same holds for exotic armor items, other exotic armor items will appear with the same dark yellow cast and you will be unable to equip them.

Comment: And what happens if you try to equip more than that?

Comment: @Sean You can't even try, the other exotics in your inventory become grayed out when you hover over them.

Comment: I tried to equip an exotic chest piece when I already had an exotic helmet equipped, and a big banner with red outlines appeared at the bottom with text to the effect of "You can only equip one exotic armor piece at a time"

Comment: Put it as an answer Turbo.

Answer (score 1):

Nope only one weapon and one armor. So pick and choose. Just because you can buy one piece of exotic gear doesn't mean it's worth it, you may want to wait to find or buy a piece that suits your play style and compliments your guns and armor. Trust me I learned the hard way

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 "Exotic" Piece of armor and 1 "Exotic" Weapon can be equipped at a time. My advice is to get the raid gear which are legendary but equivalent to the exotic gear you may want.

Answer (score -1):

You can. You put it in the vault and then open character, store it, then take it back out and try to equip it quickly. It doesn't always work though.